# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation UILabel distortion

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to rotate a UILabel by 45 degrees. I'm setting the `transform` property to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.25)` but when I do so the UILabel just disappears. If I change `0.25` to `0.26`, I can see a glimpse of the UILabel (see below)

[image: UILabel problem]

UILabel before rotation: [image: UILabel with no rotation]

Code: `self.myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.26);`

If I missed any information that might be helpful, please let me know!

### Update

It seems that the frame **must be set before** applying the rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work fine, so something else is going on that you didn't post code for. I'd recommend checking the autoresizing mask as well as anywhere else that may be manipulating the transform.  From the appearance and your description, it almost seems like it is being rotated along the wrong axis via a 3D rotation causing you to view the label side on where it has a zero width/thickness, like looking at the edge of a paper head on.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will look further. At least now I know that my code is somewhat okay :)

Comment: I used the same code elsewhere and it is working. The only difference is the label above is inside a UITableCellView.

Comment: I created my UILabel programatically and it worked. My other UILabel was made using Interface Builder. It might have been a configuration issue but I have yet found it.

Comment: I think I have figured it out, I need to set the frame **before** I use the transform attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to the problem may be with embedding your UILabel within another view and using the outer view to position the label on your screen.

Another post had mentioned the problem that I'm seeing with distortion or disappearing of the text in a UILabel. Their solution was to set all the outer springs on the UILabel. This worked for me, but then my label wasn't positioned properly on screen, especially during device rotation. So I thought embedding my UILabel in a container view would let me use the container view to position my label with just the top and right spring set while still allowing proper rotation of the UILabel within with the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

Hope this helps out someone else who is also having this problem.